# alternativ to -webkit-transition for firefox?

Tags: css, wordpress

Im using css3 for to make images black and white and then colorize them ob hover. I use -webkit-transition for a nice effekt in chrome and Safari, and a .svg solution for firefox where there is no transition for the images. Would it be possible to have transition on Firefox aswell?

Site: Svenssonsbild.se

css:

```
img.attachment-full {
filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* For Webkit browsers */
filter: gray; /* For IE 6 - 9 */
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter     id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-moz-transition` for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use this (Dummy data)

```
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;    /* Chorme  */
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease;       /* Firefox */
-ms-transition: all 500ms ease;        /* IE */
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;         /* Opera */
 transition: all 500ms ease;           /* All */
```

Comment: Thanks. Added transitions for opera, IE and Firefox. Cant test IE, but it doesnt seems to work for Firefox for me.  Could it have anything to do with the svg filter?

Comment: If you want you can use filters like that:

-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);

      filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /*Firefox*/
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1)
              filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0); /*IE*/ **

Comment: The filter i ise work, i just want the transition that webkit-transition gives.